# I've looked for a job VS I've been looking for a job

Tags: present-perfect

I'm not a native english speaker and I'd like to understand the difference between these 2 sentences:

1. I've looked for a job for 2 years.
2. I've been looking for a job for 2 years.

Does the first one mean I've just stopped ?

Comment: It does not definitely imply you have stopped, but it is far more compatible with that meaning than the other is. To make it really clear that you have stopped, use the simple past: “I looked for a job for two years.” Your second clearly implies, by contrast, that you have *not* stopped.

Answer (score 0):

'I have looked for a job for two years' could be followed by 'fortunately, I just found one'
'I looked for a job for two years' may refer to the time one spent job hunting before going onto university many years ago.
By contrast: Finding employment has been difficult; 'I have been looking for a job for two years'